# What conditions have to apply that this is a basis of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $B$ is a basis of V and $b \in V$. What conditions have to apply for
>   an element $v\in V$ that $(B-\{b\} \cup \{v\})$ is a Basis of $V$?

My approach is there must be an $a\in R$, so that $b=a*v$ or b=a?

Comment: It's sufficient, but not necessary. Necessary and sufficient condition would be for example that $b$ lies in the span of $B-\left\{b\right\}\cup \left\{v\right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is
$$v\not\in\operatorname{span}(B-\{b\})$$
in fact
let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in \Bbb R$ such that
$$\alpha_1 b_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}b_{n-1}+\alpha_n v=0$$
where 
$$(b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1})=B-\{b\}$$
so
$$\alpha_1 b_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}b_{n-1}=-\alpha_n v\in \operatorname{span}(B-\{b\})$$
so $\alpha_n=0$ and then $\alpha_i=0\;\forall i$ since $B-\{b\}$ is a linearly independent hence we conclude that $B\cup\{v\}$ is linearly independent and then it's a basis.

Comment: according your second latex statement, why only n-1 elements and not n?
if v is not in the span there must be an ...an*bn+an*v=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $B-\{b\}$ will span a subspace of $V$ with dimension $\dim(V)-1$. Therefore, $v\in V$ satisfying $(B-\{b\} \cup \{v\})$ also a basis for $V$$\iff$ $v\notin span(B-\{b\})$

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough that $$\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{span}(b)}(v)\neq 0,$$ which is equivalent to the same statement with the roles of $b$ and $v$ reversed.

This means essentially that the information lost by removing $b$ is regained by appending $v$.

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{span}(b)}$ in an arbitrary $\mathbb R$ vector space?

Comment: @Christoph: I had in mind a Hilbert space, I suppose.

Comment: In that case, orthogonal projection doesn't do the job: Consider the basis $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$. You can replace $(1,1)$ by $(1,-1)$ and still obtain a basis, but $(1,1)\perp (1,-1)$. What you want is that in the $B$-coordinates of $v$ the coordinate corresponding to $b$ doesn't vanish. So you need all of $B$ to decide that, not just $b$.

Comment: You seem to be correct. I will have to think about this some more.